# Post request in Python

Tags: python, post

I'm trying to handle what should be a simple POST.request in Python.

When I submit the form I get the following form data
[Form data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkrJf.png)

I then use the following code to try to post the form according to the above

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 BeautifulSoup
import requests
html = urlopen("http://www.kkv.se/Diariet/default.asp?nav=2")

params = {
    'dossnr_from': '0',
    'dossnr_tom': '0',
    'hitspage': '50',
    'sort': 'Regdatum',
    'hits_search': '50',
    'sortorder': 'Fallande'}

r = requests.post("http://www.konkurrensverket.se/Diariet/resultat.asp, data=params")
print(r.text)
```

But it does not post correctly and I end up back at the main page. Any ideas on what I may be doing be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try putting your close quote after asp, e.g. `..resultat.asp", data=params)`

Comment: At a guess, you probably need to submit the empty string fields. And the form may have hidden fields that also need to be submitted.

Comment: use "Developer tools" in Chrome or "Firebug" in Firefox to see what is send from browser to server when you use browser.